# aws greengrass core running in docker container on rPi3

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi3, aws-iot

I have an AWS Greengrass Core setup in a docker container.  Everything seems to check out fine, but the greengrass daemon fails to start - error is:
Greengrass deamon *xx* failed to start
Failed to create overlay fs for container nosysRootfs operation not permitted

I had the same core setup as a non-Docker container, so the certs and config.json file should be correct.

Comment: Hi @jdeason, did you find a solution?

Comment: @macbutch - I put this aside for a while waiting on official support from AWS.  The answer below referencing the Github project looks promising though.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this project on [Github](https://github.com/dzimine/aws-greengrass-docker) Its not on raspberry pi but would be helpful. For greengrass to work on rpi you would have to switch to devicemapper storage driver which is not the default with latest docker engine (overlay2 is the default)